# Selecting rows from a database based on priority

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I'm working on a simple slideshow, that takes data from a database. I've made a php loop in order to get all rows from a table in the database. It works properly (the code is written underneath the text). In the final, for each row there is a div filled with severe information. Then I used javascript to simply add and remove class "*.visible*" gradually and it loops.

But now I would like to create something like **a priority system**. I thought I would add a column into the table, where I could write a number, let's say from 1 to 3. If a row had the priority 1, it would show itself every third loop of divs, whereas if the priority was set to 3, it would be shown every loop. I just don't know how should I get it done.

I don't know if I was clear, feel free and ask me a question if you didn't understand anything.

Thanks a lot.

```
        $query = "SELECT *
                FROM tbpolozky
                WHERE active = 1";

        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();

        $produkty = $statement->fetchAll();

         ?>

         <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="cs">
         <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>DongleAd - Slideshow</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css">
         </head>
         <body>
            <div class="slider">
                <?php $i=0; foreach($produkty as $p): ?>
                <div class="slide <?php if($i==0){echo('active');} ?>">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="slide_popis">
                            <div class="popis">
                                <h1><?= $p['nazev_produktu'] ?></h1>
                                <p><?= $p['popis_produktu'] ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="logo"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide_produkt">
                            <img src="<?= $p['img_url'] ?>" alt="">
                            <span><?= $p['cena'] ?> Kč</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: In the final, the higher priority the row has, the more often the div filled with data from the row shows.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you display it by you could try it using [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) something like this

```
<?php
 $counter = 0;
  $names =array('Jose'=>'1','Javier'=>'3','Jerome'=>'1','Anna'=>'3','Joselito'=>'1','Javi'=>'3','Andrew'=>'1','Bob'=>'3','Doc'=>'1','Dope'=>'3','Brod'=>'1','Brad'=>'3',
          'Duke'=>'1','John'=>'3','Doe'=>'1','Michael'=>'3');
foreach($names as $name => $priority) {



if($priority == '1') // Check for priority first
{
 if($counter % 3 === 1 ) {
    echo "<div style = 'background-color:green;'>" . $name . "Priority no." . $priority . "</div>"; // do something every third loop ( DISPLAY THE LOWEST )
 }
}else{
     echo "<div style = 'background-color:blue;'>" . $name . "Priority no." . $priority . "</div>";  // DISPLAY THE HIGHEST 
}
++$counter;
}
?>
```